# Encrypting a list of words with crypt

Tags: c, encryption

I am working on this: http://d2o9nyf4hwsci4.cloudfront.net/2014/spring/psets/2/hacker2/hacker2.html

and I am trying to make a list of encrpyted 8 letters words from /usr/share/dict/words, here's what I got so far. I am using the salt HA and 50.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int FindWord();
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 2)  
    {
        printf("Invalid Argument");
        return 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
      FindWord();  
    }
int FindWord()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    fp1 = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("EncrpytedPassword.txt","a+");
    char *Line = fgets(char *line[9], int 9, fp1);
    while (fgets(char *line[9], int 9, fp1) != EOF)
    {
         char *EncryptLine1 = crypt(Line, const char *50); 
         fputs(EncryptLine1, fp2);
         char *EncryptLine2 = crypt(Line, const char *"HA");
         fputs(EncryptLine2, fp2);
    }
} 





**crack.c:26:24: error: expected expression
char *Line = fgets(char *line[9], int 9, fp1);
                   ^
crack.c:27:18: error: expected expression
    while (fgets(char *line[9], int 9, fp1) != EOF)
             ^
crack.c:29:43: error: expected expression
         char *EncryptLine1 = crypt(Line, const char *50); 
                                      ^
crack.c:31:43: error: expected expression
         char *EncryptLine2 = crypt(Line, const char *"HA");
                       **
```

Comment: And your problem is ?

Comment: It won't compile due to "expected expression"

Comment: edit in the entire error message

Comment: Are you sure that requesting help here at SO is ethical? [Academic Honesty:Not Reasonable:Searching for or soliciting outright solutions to problem sets online or elsewhere.]

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer I am not following the class per say, just learning from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems in your code :

false :

```
char *Line = fgets(char *line[9], int 9, fp1);
```

correct :

```
char line[9];
fgets(line, 9, fp1);
```

Why that :

```
  char *Line = fgets(char *line[9], int 9, fp1);
    while (fgets(char *line[9], int 9, fp1) != EOF)
```

And not that ? :

```
char line[9];
while (fgets(line, 9, fp1) != NULL)
```

Plus, your word file is 139719 lines long. Are you sure you want to do that ?

False :

```
char *EncryptLine1 = crypt(Line, const char *50);
```

True :

```
char *EncryptLine1 = crypt(Line, "50");
```

Correct this compile with -lcrypt and the good includes and there is no "expected expression"

(write "\n" after each hash in the file could be great)

Note that it's more clear to declare EncryptLine1 and EncryptLine2 at the begining of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely not sure what exactly is being asked, but assuming that there is some problem in the code given, and assuming that a waypoint to resolve the issue is being asked: The opening and closing typecast parentheses are missing in code.

The `line` does not exist as far as you've disclosed to us. The way you seem to be trying to use the `fgets` is truly unconventional, but the following would work:

```
char *Line = fgets((char[9]) { 0 }, (int) 9, fp1);
```

Instead of what you wrote. There, the `{ 0 }` would be typecast into an array of `9` characters, dynamically allocating memory until the end of that scope, which then would be sent as a parameter to `fgets`. `Line` would then receive the address of that dynamically allocated memory location, since `fgets` returns its first argument, except for when an error occurs.

I wish I could provide the document I'm relying on for my statement about that memory location being guaranteed to be available until the end of that scope.

I don't know what you're trying with `(const char *) 50`, but it won't work. If you were hoping to pass the single character with the ASCII code `50` as a string, then you could write `(const char[]) { 50, 0 }` there. Or rather `(const char *) "50"` if you want to use the string `"50"`.

Comment: Being "absolutely not sure what exactly is being asked" you should have flagged the post instead of answering.